# MultiThread span propagation in java

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, open-telemetry

I am trying to insert Open Telemetry inside my java application in order to verify if this solution can be used for requests tracking within a microservices architecture.

In my scenario, "Application A" produces a message on a RabbitMQ queue while "Application B" consumes the message from RabbitMQ (both applications are using Spring AMQP).
Within the messages published by "Application A", the traceparent is correctly present, which goes up to "Application B".

The message is consumed by the **BlockingQueueConsumer**, in whose log the *trace_id* and the *span_id* are correctly present and logged by slf4j.
BlockingQueueConsumer then delegates the processing of the message to the **BlockingQueueConsumer** which runs inside another Thread and from there on the *trace_id* and the *span_id* are lost.

Is it the OpenTelemetry normal behaviour?
What about context propagation from different threads?

Thanks
Damy

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can tell you that if you use the `DirectMessageListenerContainer` the listener will be called on the amqp-client thread: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#choose-container

Comment: Hi Gary,
Thanks for your answer.
I would also be interested in understanding if and how OpenTelemetry deals with context propagation in an application that delegates part of its business logic to other threads